# Code Chef's Cleaning Tables: find the minimum number of tables to clean

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge

**Description:**

> Haku has been newly hired by Chef to clean tables at his restaurant.
>   So whenever a customer wants a table, Haku must clean it.
>
> But Haku happens to be a lazy boy. So in the morning, when the
>   restaurant is opened, all the tables are dirty from night before.
>
> The customer don't leave the table unless they are politely requested
>   to do so. And customers can order meal later again. So if they were
>   already having a table, they can be served on the same table [Haku
>   doesn't have to clean :)]. But if they don't have a table then they
>   must be given some table [Haku must clean :(]
>
> The restaurant has N tables. When a customer requires a table, he/she
>   can occupy any unoccupied table. However if all tables are occupied,
>   then Haku is free to ask politely any customer to leave his/her table.
>   And the freed table can be given to the waiting customer.
>
> Now Chef has the psychic ability to tell the order of customer meal
>   requests for the entire day. Given this list, help Haku find the
>   minimum number of times he has to clean the tables.

[Link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLETAB)

**Input:**

First line contains integer `T`, number of test cases. First line of each test case contains 2 integers `N`, number of tables and `M`, number of customer orders. Followed by `M` integers on next line, which is the order in which customers ask for meal. Customers are referenced by integer `C`.

**Output:**

For each test case output the minimum number of times Haku must clean the table(s).

**Code:**

```
class Main {
  public static int solve(int N, int[] orders) {
    Map<Integer, LinkedList> positions = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      int order = orders[i];
      positions.computeIfAbsent(order, x -> new LinkedList<Integer>()).add(i);
    }
    Set<Integer> table = new HashSet<>();
    //System.out.println(positions);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      int order = orders[i];
      if (table.contains(order)) {
        positions.get(order).removeFirst(); // remove the first entry
        continue;
      }
      count++;
      if (table.size() < N) {
        positions.get(order).removeFirst(); // remove the first entry
        table.add(order);
        continue;
      } else {
        int farthestOrder = findIndex(table, orders, i, positions);
        table.remove(farthestOrder);
        table.add(order);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Count: " + count);
    return count;
  }

  private static int findIndex(
      Set<Integer> table, int[] orders, int i, Map<Integer, LinkedList> positions) {
    // case 1: There is at least one order which is not seen in future
    for (int order : orders) {
      if (positions.get(order).size() == 0) {
        return order;
      }
    }
    // case 2: All the orders can be seen, find farthest
    int max = -1;
    for (; i < orders.length; i++) {
      int order = orders[i];
      int position = (int) positions.get(order).getLast();
      max = Math.max(position, max);
    }
    return orders[max];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    solve(2, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
    solve(2, new int[]{4, 1});
    solve(3, new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1});
    solve(3, new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 4});
  }
}
```

**Question(s):**

I assume that the solution is \$O(N^2)\$ where \$N\$ is the number of orders.
Is there any linear time algorithm possible?

Comment: Try `solve(2, new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5});`.  It should return something like 7, but I suspect that it will actually return 5, as `findIndex` repeatedly finds that 2 no longer needs a table but 2 no longer has a table to be removed.  So you'll end up with four customers seated at two tables.  Hint:  the `findIndex` method does not need `orders`, as `table` and `positions` have all the necessary information.  Also, `getLast` should probably be `getFirst`.  Consider `solve(2, new int[] {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1}`.  That should kick out 1 so that Haku only has to clean 4, not 7.

Comment: Imho `getLast` is fine because it will return the correct answer which is `4` which aligns my algorithm to remove the farthest order, I am still thinking about your first half of your comment.

Comment: Iterating over `table` gives me the correct result now.

Comment: Sorry, `solve(2, new int[] {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3}`

Comment: Makes sense, so the last example should return `4` right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.